# translating to ascii 31 (unit separator)

Tags: ascii, tr

I have a csv file that i would like to print in a file replacing the comma with the non printable ASCII 31 Unit separator.
I am trying it like this:

```
 echo ${out} | tr ',' '\31' > ${in}
```

I use vim as editor and i know that in vim i should see `^_` if that `tr` command was successfull, but unfortunatelly i see `^y`
Anyone out there who could suggest a solution?

Comment: try '\031`. Good luck. (that's a zero).

Comment: is 037, 037 is the octal value of 31

Comment: dbl-zzzz ;-) . Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is:

`echo ${out} | tr ',' '\037' > ${in}`

31 is 037 when converted into octal